# Need to automatically determine text that will cause a Regex match

Tags: regex

I need to provide the text that would automatically match a Regular Expression.

For example, given the Regex: `[Tt]rue`
I need to generate `True` or `true`.

I only need to generate one valid match per Regex, hopefully that makes it an easier problem to solve in regards to the infinite possibilities that can come with Regex.

I'm not sure if this is even possible due to how regular expressions are built. Also, I'm not sure what I would search for.  The more common problem of 'inverting' a match tends to drown out my problem.

If it matters, I'm using C#.  If a solution requires another technology, that's fine as well.

Answer:
I was pointed to Xeger, a Java library for this, which led me to:
https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare
Which is a C# port of Xeger and dk.brics.automaton which Xeger uses.

Comment: How would you handle quantifiers or wildcards? Surely `.+` would enter an infinite loop.

Comment: I actually just need to generate one valid match.  So, any valid match would do for my purposes.  I'll update my question with this.  Thanks.

Comment: I've never checked, but is the code behind regex101.com freely available?    The issue tracker at least is on github, don't know about the source itself.  If so, you may be able to use the algorithm that generates the explanation to instead generate a matching piece of text

Comment: What extensions on regexes should be supported? Is the basic version enough, or should it support Perl ones?

Comment: @AdamSmith: you can always use *breadth-first search* to prevent getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @CommuSoft The original question asked to generate ALL text that would match a given regex. `.+` matches an infinite number of strings, breadth- or depth- first :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: yes that's indeed impossible. Even determining whether there are an infinite amount of strings can be impossible for *Perl* regexes, because they are Turing complete. For traditional ones, that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using **[Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/)** (*A Java library for generating random text from regular expressions*)

From its documentation it says:

> Think of it as the opposite of regular expression matchers. **This
>   library allows you to generate text that is guaranteed to match a
>   regular expression passed in**.
>
> Let's take the regular expression:
>
> [ab]{4,6}c
>
> Using Xeger, you can now
>   generate Strings matching this pattern like this:

```
String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```

Xeger site also recommends to check its limitations. Here you can find what they defined by limitations:

```
regexp  ::=     unionexp                
|                       
unionexp        ::=     interexp | unionexp     (union) 
|       interexp                
interexp        ::=     concatexp & interexp    (intersection)  [OPTIONAL]
|       concatexp               
concatexp       ::=     repeatexp concatexp     (concatenation) 
|       repeatexp               
repeatexp       ::=     repeatexp ?     (zero or one occurrence)        
|       repeatexp *     (zero or more occurrences)      
|       repeatexp +     (one or more occurrences)       
|       repeatexp {n}   (n occurrences) 
|       repeatexp {n,}  (n or more occurrences) 
|       repeatexp {n,m} (n to m occurrences, including both)    
|       complexp                
complexp        ::=     ~ complexp      (complement)    [OPTIONAL]
|       charclassexp            
charclassexp    ::=     [ charclasses ] (character class)       
|       [^ charclasses ]        (negated character class)       
|       simpleexp               
charclasses     ::=     charclass charclasses           
|       charclass               
charclass       ::=     charexp - charexp       (character range, including end-points) 
|       charexp         
simpleexp       ::=     charexp         
|       .       (any single character)  
|       #       (the empty language)    [OPTIONAL]
|       @       (any string)    [OPTIONAL]
|       " <Unicode string without double-quotes> "      (a string)      
|       ( )     (the empty string)      
|       ( unionexp )    (precedence override)   
|       < <identifier> >        (named automaton)       [OPTIONAL]
|       <n-m>   (numerical interval)    [OPTIONAL]
charexp ::=     <Unicode character>     (a single non-reserved character)       
|       \ <Unicode character>   (a single character)
```

I think you should test simple regex and add a more complex functionality progressively in order to find if it helps you generating your data

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Xeger.
Researching Xeger led me to:
https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare
which is a port of the main Automaton library that Xeger uses.  Fare also happened to have a C# port of Xeger which seems to work quite well without having to navigate my code through Java.

The Unit Tests in Fare show Xeger usage, but you can get up and running in 1 line of code once the Nuget package for it is downloaded.